# pyninstaller error: ignored explicit argument '--'

Tags: python, pyinstaller, command-prompt, boxplot

i've done a simple script for plotting of boxplot, usingi three module, numpy, os for the path and matplotlib.pyplot.
when i lunched pyinstaller from terminal i wrote down this command:

```
(spyder_env) D:\Scipts_homemade>pyinstaller -F-- hiddenimport=numpy -F--hiddenimport=os -F--hiddenimport=matplotlib.pyplot -F--collect-submodules=numpy -F--collect-submodules=matplotlib.pyplot -F--onefile BOX_PLOT_interactive.py
```

the output is:

```
pyinstaller: error: argument -F/--onefile: ignored explicit argument '--''
where is my mistake?
```

thank you

some help for my mistake, maybe due to an incorrect command or a module missed

Answer (score 1):

`-F` and `--onefile` are the same thing.

Also, it should be `--hidden-import` not `--hiddenimport`

Do like this:

```
pyinstaller --onefile --hidden-import=numpy --hidden-import=os --hidden-import=matplotlib.pyplot --collect-submodules=numpy --collect-submodules=matplotlib.pyplot BOX_PLOT_interactive.py
```

Comment: really thank you, i found the error, was the space before hiddenimport anthe lack of it after F. now it's working, thank yoy